# A very specific synonym for a potatoes au gratin type recipe

Tags: potatoes

Many years ago, we went to a restaurant that served a little cube of potatoes that was in the same category as my Mom's scalloped potatoes, but much more refined. It was not soupy, and the potatoes were sliced very thin.

Since then I have seen the specific name just once, and I have not been successful at finding it through a Google search which always rolls back around to the word au gratin.

Comment: Maybe potato pave?

Comment: Escalloped? or Scalloped?

Comment: "Scalloped" may be a regional term. My Mom's family was made up of Ohio farmers.

Comment: Looks like potato pave is what I'm looking for. Can you make your comment into an answer so I can check it? http://numnums.com/recipes/199/thomas-keller-s-potato-pave

Answer (score 1):

I think Potatoes Dauphinois maybe what you are looking for. Thin sliced potatoes seasoned with salt, pepper and garlic, covered in cream (often topped with cheese) then baked in a gratin dish.